# getting undefined validator control value form validators

Tags: validation, angular

I build a custom validator.

```
 this.slideOneForm = formBuilder.group({
        remise: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(2), Validators.pattern('[1-9 ]*')]),Validator.isValid],
        quantite: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(2), Validators.pattern('[1-9 ]*')])],
    });
```

this is the implementation of the custom validator which is called at the remise line:

```
export class Validator {
    static isValid(control: FormControl): any {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(control.value,"control.value");
                if (control.value > 50) {
                    resolve({
                        "remise ne peut pas passer 50% !": true
                    });
                } 
                else {
                    resolve(null);
                }
            }, 50);
        });
    }
}
```

when I test with values like: 10,20,30,40, the value at the console is "undefined". When I test with 1, 25 or any number < 50 it works perfectly.

How can I resolve the problem?
thank you in advance.

Comment: you are removing 0 from the equation, so I say everything with a zero is ignored.